# Alert View's Frame

Tags: iphone

Can we set the frame for an alert view, actually I need to show an alert which will cover the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an 'alert' that covers the entire screen, just present a modal view controller. It will give you as much customization as you want, and will obviously cover the entire screen.